# Every commutative ring is a quotient of a normal ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

In the book *Étale cohomology* by Milne I found on p. 37 (in the context of constructing the henselization of a local ring) the following claim: 
"Every ring is a quotient of a normal ring". The same is used in *Local rings* by Nagata on p. 180.

Why is this true? Both Milne and Nagata don't explain this so it seems I'm just too blind.

Is this only true for $R$ a *local* ring or is it also true for any commutative ring?

Is there a global version of this statement? Is it true that for any scheme $X$ there is a locally closed embedding $X \hookrightarrow Y$ into a normal scheme $Y$? Is there an official term for such an embedding?

**EDIT**. Perfect answer by Pete below led me to the following additional question I should have asked above already: Is any *noetherian* ring a quotient of a normal *noetherian* ring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most natural family of rings which comes to mind as having every commutative ring as a quotient is $\mathbb{Z}[\{t_i \mid i \in I\}]$, i.e., a polynomial ring in an arbitrary set of indeterminates over $\mathbb{Z}$.  These rings are all UFDs -- see e.g. Corollary 15.27 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf) -- hence integrally closed ("normal").

Comment: Excellent, thanks! If $R$ is noetherian is it possible to find a noetherian normal ring having $R$ as quotient?

Comment: @ULT: Off the top of my head, I don't know.  (In fact I believe I gave you the only explicit family of commutative rings I know which has every commutative ring as a quotient...)

Comment: You're right. I would guess it's wrong but I don't know a counter-example.

Comment: I think a counter-example is discussed here actually: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162030/is-every-noetherian-commutative-ring-a-quotient-of-a-noetherian-domain. I don't believe that normality makes things better.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark could you please recommend me some notes regarding that every commutative ring is a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[t_i]$. I am having some trouble to understand that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it like take $t_i$ as elements of $R$, since $i$ is over any index set $I$, $Z[t_i] \rightarrow R$ is surjective, mapping $t_i$ to $r_i$.